# Translate string on Drupal: Source string not found

Tags: drupal-7

I want to translate some remaining strings I couldn't translate by importing the translation file.

when I enter to the translate interface of the string I got : "Source string not found" and the textfield is disabled.

How can I do to translate these strings?

Comment: See https://gbyte.co/blog/when-custom-t-strings-are-missing-from-translate-interface

Answer (score 0):

Use Internationalization(i18n) module. In the configuration page navigate to 'Strings' and select all radio buttons and  click on the 'refresh strings' button.